# first-child:first-letter not working in a list

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to make a list that has a different first letter for some of the items in the main menu. I have the first-letter psuedo element working across the list, but don't want it to show on the first and last child in the list.

```
.main-navigation li a:first-letter {
color: #e88a2a;
}

.main-navigation li ul li a:first-letter {
color: #6a6a6a;
}
```

I'm using the first part this code to colour the first letter in the menu items, and then the second part to stop the sub-menu items taking that colour.

However, trying to use

```
 .main-navigation li a:first-child:first-letter {
 color: #f0f0f0;
 }
```

is giving every first letter in the menu items and sub-menu items that colour, rather than just the first one (Home in my fiddle)

I want Home and Contact Us not to show the orange colour, or else show a different colour (the default one), whichever is easiest. Can someone help?

http://jsfiddle.net/wM9eA/

Comment: All of your `a` elements are the `first-child` of their respective `li` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `:first-child` applies to the element that it's applied to directly, while `:first-letter` applies to that element's content. Saying `a:first-child` will pick the first `a` inside the `li`, and there are only one `a` in each `li`. We need to apply select that to the `li`.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wM9eA/3/)**

```
.main-navigation li:first-child a:first-letter {
    color: #e88a2a;
}

.main-navigation li ul li:first-child a:first-letter {
    color: #6a6a6a;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to target the li element with `first-child`, the same goes for `last-child`.

```
.main-navigation li:first-child a:first-letter,
.main-navigation li:last-child a:first-letter{
   color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wM9eA/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You want the first and last li elements.

```
.main-navigation li:first-child a:first-letter,
.main-navigation li:last-child a:first-letter {
    color: inherit;
}
```